# c# function with same arguments return different results on multiple runs

Tags: c#, function, arguments, return

I have a c# function that i have as part of a bigger algo that im designing however that function is acting weird. It is calculating different results for fitness on multiple runs with the same arguments. I do not see where the problem is in the function. Any enlightened suggestion would be welcome.

```
private readonly Dictionary<int,decimal>_cache = new Dictionary<int, decimal>(); // lookup cache
    private void CalculateFitness(TimeTable timeTable)
    {                      
        const int points = 1;            

        var exams = timeTable.Exams.ToList();
        var combinations = exams.Select(x => exams.Where(y => exams.IndexOf(y) > exams.IndexOf(x))
                                                          .Select(z => new List<Exam> { x, z }))
                                                          .SelectMany(x => x);


        var clash = combinations.Where(touple => touple[0].Period.Id == touple[1].Period.Id && touple[0].Date == touple[1].Date && touple[0].Students.Intersect(touple[1].Students).Any());
        var clCount = clash.Sum(touple => touple[0].Students.Intersect(touple[1].Students).Count());            



        var score = clCount == 0 ? timeTable.Exams.Count : timeTable.Exams.Count - clCount;


        if (_cache.ContainsKey(score))
        {
            timeTable.Fitness = _cache[score];
        }
        else
        {
            timeTable.Fitness = Math.Abs(decimal.Divide(score, (timeTable.Exams.Count * points))); // Calculate Fitness 
            _cache.Add(score, timeTable.Fitness);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's difficult to give an enlightened suggestions if you don't show us anything.

Comment: Then function is really badly written. Show us some code.

Comment: The good news at least is that you're not using the XKCD random number generator.

Comment: Hard for `void` to not be `void`. However, consider the two apparent side-effects: `timeTable.Fitness` (not read directly, but see `timeTable.Exams`) and `_cache` (modified/read directly with `Add` and `ContainsKey`). Or it could be entirely different.

Comment: Have yopu stepped through the code to see where difference starts occurring (e.g. is `combinations` different, or `clash` or `clCount`, ...)?

Comment: i think the problem resides in another piece of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It is returning different results on
>   multiple runs for the same arguments

That means your function is not side effect free - you are changing or using global state somewhere. Find and eliminate those and the function should always return the expected value.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this function relies on same dynamic data. Method body would help a lot.

What makes you think that it is impossible to not have different results for the same arguments? C# is not a functional language, after all.

Comment: +1 However, "functional language" should be "pure functional language" IMOHO -- F#/OCaml are often considered "functional languages" even if they are not "pure" like Haskell.

Answer (score 0):

Another classic for this problem is:

```
foreach (var foo in myFooList)
{
    DoSomethingAsync(() => { SomeFunctionToExecute(foo); }
}
```

(access to modified closure)